# How do you pass/receive route props in components?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building a simple app with create-react-app so that I can learn React.

My **index.js** file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from "react-router";
import './index.css';
import Exercise from './Exercise';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/exercise1" component={Exercise} source={'https://hyperlinkgoeshere.com'} />
</Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

My **Exercise.js** component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class Exercise extends Component {
render() {
return(
<div className="exercise">
<iframe scrolling='no' title='exercise' src='' frameBorder="no" allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
export default Exercise;
```

What I want to achieve is to pass that link inside the source prop to an iframe inside the Exercise component.

What I don't know/was not able to find out is how do you "receive" those props and use them inside the Exercise component.

*If I need to attach any other info in order to make this question clear and reach others that might have this issue, please let me know.

Comment: Can you please edit and give us at least part of the code for index.js. It will be much easier to help you here.

Comment: @VlatkoVlahek I've formatted my question. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sure, check the answer below.

Comment: @VlatkoVlahek I've also added the code of my exercise component. I've checked your answer but now I'm not sure what to write in the source attribute of the iframe inside of the Exercise component. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is not the issue here.

In order to use the source value in your Exercise component, you need to do this:

```
<iframe scrolling='no' title='exercise' src={this.props.route.source} frameBorder="no" 
allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

So, your **index.js** should be like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from "react-router";
import './index.css';
import Exercise from './Exercise';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/exercise1" component={Exercise} source={'https://hyperlinkgoeshere.com'} />
</Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

and your **Exercise.js** should look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class Exercise extends Component {
render() {
return(
<div className="exercise">
<iframe scrolling='no' title='exercise' src={this.props.route.source} frameBorder="no" allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
export default Exercise;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass a prop to a component inside React router v4, then this is the following way.

**Component without props**

```
<Route path="/exercise1" component={Exercise} />
```

**Component with props**

```
<Route path="/exercise1" render={(props) => <Exercise {...props} source={source} />} />
```

Make sure you don't miss the difference between *component* in the first example and *render* in the second one. If you use an anonymous function like this inside the component prop instead of render it will cause a lot of component mounting / unmounting that you don't expect.

Comment: But how do I reference that source property inside the Exercise component? I have added the code for the component too but it seems that doing something like src={this.props.source} doesn't work.